# How to speed up optimization using parallel

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib

I am doing optimization using `optimize.minimize` from `scipy`, say the objective function is `fun`.

I need to do optimization for each row of my dataframe, and currently I am using `Parallel` from `joblib`:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from joblib import Parallel,delayed
import multiprocessing
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
import numpy as np
import jax

df=pd.DataFrame()
rng = np.random.default_rng()
df[["p11", "p12", "p13"]]=rng.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1120)
df[["s1", "s2", "s3"]]=rng.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1120)


num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1

def get_attraction(b1,b2, b3):
    c1 = 20 * b1 + 12 * b2 + 6 * b3
    c2 = 12 * b1 + 24 * b2 + 18 * b3
    c3 = 0 * b1 + 14 * b2 + 30 * b3
    return c1,c2,c3

def get_a_tau_max(p1_tau, p2_tau, p3_tau, a):
    b1_tau_l1_a1_a1 = p1_tau * (1 - a) + a
    b2_tau_l1_a1_a1 = p2_tau * (1 - a)
    b3_tau_l1_a1_a1 = p3_tau * (1 - a)

    a1_tau_l1_a1, a2_tau_l1_a1, a3_tau_l1_a1 = get_attraction(b1_tau_l1_a1_a1, b2_tau_l1_a1_a1,b3_tau_l1_a1_a1)

    b1_tau_l1_a1_a2 = p1_tau * (1 - a)
    b2_tau_l1_a1_a2 = p2_tau * (1 - a) + a
    b3_tau_l1_a1_a2 = p3_tau * (1 - a)
    a1_tau_l1_a2, a2_tau_l1_a2, a3_tau_l1_a2 = get_attraction(b1_tau_l1_a1_a2, b2_tau_l1_a1_a2,b3_tau_l1_a1_a2)

    b1_tau_l1_a1_a3 = p1_tau * (1 - a)
    b2_tau_l1_a1_a3 = p2_tau * (1 - a)
    b3_tau_l1_a1_a3 = p3_tau * (1 - a) + a
    a1_tau_l1_a3, a2_tau_l1_a3, a3_tau_l1_a3 = get_attraction(b1_tau_l1_a1_a3, b2_tau_l1_a1_a3,b3_tau_l1_a1_a3)

    a_tau_max = max(a1_tau_l1_a1, a2_tau_l1_a2, a3_tau_l1_a3)

    return a_tau_max

def get_signal_conditional_at(at, b1, b2, b3, a):

    if at==1:
        b1_tau = b1 * (1-a) + a
        b2_tau = b2 * (1-a)
        b3_tau = b3 * (1-a)
    elif at==2:
        b1_tau = b1 * (1-a)
        b2_tau = b2 * (1-a) + a
        b3_tau = b3 * (1-a)
    else:
        b1_tau = b1 * (1-a)
        b2_tau = b2 * (1-a)
        b3_tau = b3 * (1-a) + a
    return b1_tau, b2_tau, b3_tau

def get_belief(index,row):
    if index <= 1118:
        df_mask = pd.DataFrame()
        df_mask["weight"] = [0.8 ** i for i in range(0, index+1)][::-1]
        dem = df_mask["weight"].sum()

        subdf = df.iloc[:index].copy()
        s1_history = subdf["s1"].values.tolist()
        s2_history = subdf["s2"].values.tolist()
        s3_history = subdf["s3"].values.tolist()

        belief=[]
        for at in [[row["b11"], row["b12"], row["b13"]],
                    [row["b21"], row["b22"], row["b23"]],
                    [row["b31"], row["b32"], row["b32"]]]:

            df_mask["s1"] = s1_history + [at[0]]
            df_mask["s2"] = s2_history + [at[1]]
            df_mask["s3"] = s3_history + [at[2]]

            nom1 = (df_mask["weight"] * df_mask["s1"]).sum()
            nom2 = (df_mask["weight"] * df_mask["s2"]).sum()
            nom3 = (df_mask["weight"] * df_mask["s3"]).sum()

            b1 = nom1 / dem
            b2 = nom2 / dem
            b3 = nom3 / dem
            belief += [b1,b2,b3]
        return belief
    else:
        return [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]


def get_prob(x, index,row, lamda, a): #
    p1, p2, p3 = x[0], x[1], x[2]

    p11 = row["p11"]
    p12 = row["p12"]
    p13 = row["p13"]

    b1 = p11 * (1-a) + p1 * a
    b2 = p12 * (1-a) + p2 * a
    b3 = p13 * (1-a) + p3 * a

    c1,c2,c3=get_attraction(b1,b2,b3)

    row["b11"], row["b12"], row["b13"] = get_signal_conditional_at(1, p11,p12,p13,a)
    row["b21"], row["b22"], row["b23"] = get_signal_conditional_at(2, p11,p12,p13,a)
    row["b31"], row["b32"], row["b33"] = get_signal_conditional_at(3, p11,p12,p13,a)

    belief = get_belief(index,row)

    t1 = get_a_tau_max(belief[0], belief[1], belief[2], a)
    t2 = get_a_tau_max(belief[3], belief[4], belief[5], a)
    t3 = get_a_tau_max(belief[6], belief[7], belief[8], a)

    a1 = c1+t1
    a2 = c2+t2
    a3 = c3+t3

    nom1 = np.exp(lamda*a1)
    nom2 = np.exp(lamda*a2)
    nom3 = np.exp(lamda*a3)
    dem = nom1 + nom2 + nom3

    p1_t = nom1 / dem
    p2_t = nom2 / dem
    p3_t = nom3 / dem

    return (p1_t - p1) ** 2 + (p2_t - p2) ** 2 + (p3_t - p3) ** 2

def get_root(index,row,lamda,a):
        fun = get_prob
        #jac_ = jax.jacfwd(fun)
        result = basinhopping(fun, x0=[0.0, 0.25, 0.75], niter=50, interval=10, seed=np.random.seed(0),
                              minimizer_kwargs={'args': (index,row,lamda,a), #'jac':jac_,
                                                'method': "SLSQP",
                                                'tol': 1.0e-4,
                                                'bounds': [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0)],
                                                'constraints': {"type": 'eq',
                                                                'fun': lambda x: 1 - x[0] - x[1] - x[2],
                                                                'jac': lambda x: np.full_like(x,-1)}})
        x=np.append(result.x, index)
        return x

start = time.time()
p_sv = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(get_root)(index=index, row=row, lamda=0.5,a=7/13)
                                  for index, row in df.iterrows())
print("elapsed:", time.time() - start)
elapsed: 240.9707179069519
```

Each optimization is independent, there is no information exchange between the rows.

It takes very long to finish the optimization for the whole dataset, and it only occupies about 30% of CPU (I have M1 pro).

My questions is how many `n_jobs` I should set (or there is some other way such as change backend) to make it use 100% CPU such that I can finish this program faster?

I have access to a computer cluster which has 2 CPUs and 64 core per CPU. I have tried to set `n_job=64` it does not provide significant improvement (I am still learning how to utilize 2 CPUs..).

Update:
Now I figured that providing Jacobian of the objective function slows down optimization. With 80 rows, with `jac_` it takes 64 seconds, without it it take 20 seconds (and CPU goes almost 100%). But why? I thought providing Jacobian would make it faster.

Update:
I add an `fun` and `df` with 1120 rows. If I do not use `jac_`, it is about 5 times faster using the cluster.

Comment: Note that the M1 processor is a big little processors. This architecture adds a lot of complication with parallel programming. For example, processes can be scheduled on wrong cores or synchronization can be much more expensive. Using far more jobs can cores often make things slower because multiple processes needs to be scheduled on the same core. Switching from one process to another on a core is expensive. The number of job should not be bigger than x2 the number of core in general.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Are those affirmations backed by any relevant performance benchmark or observation? Moreover, even if this was true (that "[M1] architecture adds a lot of complication with parallel programming") i still fail to see how this would apply to the OP question since you don't show any evidence of this phenomenon in its program. Note that the OP also tried on another machine (likely not M1) and in its code the number of core is already "not bigger than 2x the number of cores".

Comment: @LouisLac Well this is pretty basic knowledge. Any uniform fork-join parallel code with a static scheduling have issue on big-little CPUs. For example, you can make a test with the OpenMP examples. The same applies with Python which use the same model (but with processes). This is not specific to the M1 : recent Intel CPUs now have the same issue (eg. AlderLake). This is one reason why Intel built ThreadDirector btw. I agree that there is no strong evidence this is the problem (hence this comment and not an answer). It just a wild guess based on previous posts, waiting for more information

Comment: @jasmine How many row there are in the dataframe? If there are many row, the job submission can be slower than the parallel computation (because data needs to be pickled+sent+unpickled). Can you please provide a *minimal reproducible example* or *profiling information*?

Comment: @JérômeRichard `fun` is `get_prob` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77480913/find-non-negative-roots-of-a-system-of-equations-using-scipy-optimize-root) except that I change `return` to `(p1_t - p1)**2+(p2_t - p2)**2+(p3_t - p3)**2` in order to do minimization. I have 1120 rows, and I have 24 such dataset. So far when I use the cluster (using AMD node), I use the code above and submit one job.

Comment: @JérômeRichard That doesn't seem true either. M processors and Intel ones use vastly different architectures in every aspects, [including the schedulers](https://eclecticlight.co/2022/10/03/making-the-most-of-apple-silicon-power-1-m-series-chips-are-different/). Contrary to what your first comment suggests, the M1 Pro [shows very strong multiprocessing capabilities](https://www.anandtech.com/show/17024/apple-m1-max-performance-review/5) and the big.LITTLE architecture doesn't seem to affect the MP scalability. The OP hardware is likely adequate and won't cause complications with MP.

Comment: @jasmine Please, could you post the whole data (pandas dataframe) you are using so that we can produce your issue?

Comment: @LouisLac I disagree on the Intel part of the article. I do not see why ITD and more generally EHFI is less flexible than the supposed full kernel scheduling approach. In fact, ITD require changes in the kernel scheduler so to consider the big-little architecture. The scheduling behaviour of ITD is quite different than the one of Apple on the M1 but the point stay the same.

Comment: @LouisLac Kernel schedulers often fail to place threads correctly. This is why we nearly always manually bind them to cores in HPC applications/runtimes. Many people complains about E core being wrongly used in their application, even here on S.O., including on the M1, Alderlake and similar CPUs.

Comment: @LouisLac The benchmarks prove nothing about scalability. First of all, in my comment, I explicitly stated "with a static scheduling". Did you check this is the case in the code? It looks like the code is neither open nor even free ([actually their benchmark are very expensive](https://www.spec.org/order.html)) so I cannot tell. Moreover, the website compare different processors (with different memory subsystem), not the scalability of one processor. You cannot use this to evaluate the scalability of applications on 1 specific CPU. Performance and scalability are two different thing.

Comment: @LouisLac A note on *"the big.LITTLE architecture doesn't seem to affect the MP scalability"* : there is an entire field of research in parallelism where people (like me) focus on the scalability of algorithm on heterogeneous systems (including big.little, though not me). There are many research papers on this topic you can find in heterogeneous computing conferences. [Here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7965115) is just one example. Anyway, one said, I agree that this is unlikely for this issue to be the one of the OP based on the new information and your article on the M1 pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a multi-processing issue but an algorithmic complexity one. The function `get_prob` you are trying to optimize depends on `get_belief` which  is of worst-case linear complexity with respect to the `index` number. The consequence is that your program is of quadratic complexity, which can be a huge slowdown.

In itself, the function `get_belief` if very slow. The problem is that `get_prob` (and thus `get_belief`) will be called many times by the optimizer during the optimization process, thus slowing down the whole execution. If you remove it or replace it by a constant value (for instance replace `index <= 118` by `False` to short-circuit the expensive code path) you'll see that your program is significantly faster. On my computer this resulted in a 20x speed.

However, one can note that `get_belief` does not depend on the variable `x` of the optimized function `fun` but only on the row parameters. This likely means that you could pre-compute `get_belief` for each row of your data-frame instead of computing it inside the optimized function, thus improving the execution speed by a large margin.

Comment: You save my day!!!!